# How to capture all browser's tabs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, browser

Current I make a tool to capture image of all browser's tabs (IE, Firefox, ...).

I begin with IE browser by follow steps:

1. Scan all handles by [EnumWindows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Get class name of each handle by [GetClassName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to compare with "Internet Explorer" to get IE handle.
3. Get all tabs handle by [EnumChildWindows()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
4. Use [BitBlt()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [PrintWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture handle into .bmp file.

**I got some issues:**

**1. Can NOT capture non-active tab** (It has same image with active despite of separate page)

**2. Can NOT capture when minimized**

***Question: Could you give me any advices for these issues?***

P/S: Other information:

- Window 7 64-bits, Aero theme
- MS Visual Studio 2012
- IE 11

Many thanks!

Comment: How much experience do you have with Detours or DLL injection?

Comment: @Zephyr Pellerin I'm just a newbie on this major.

Comment: This is a tricky challenge and will require reading quite a bit of source code and familiarizing yourself with the hooking facilities available to you in Windows. A slightly easier path would be to get a picture of the last tab that is *updated* every time the user changes tabs.

Comment: ***"A slightly easier... changes tabs"*** => I think this is not good solution because the content of tab can be changed despite of non-active. ***"This is a tricky...in Windows"*** => Could you give please me documents, keywords about this? I will research them. thanks!

Comment: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~junfeng/10fa-e6998/papers/detours.pdf

Comment: It looks like you assume that invisible tabs are rendered even though they're invisible.

Comment: @MSalters, Yes, I think so. ***Example1***: when I access an URL (tab1) but the network is slow (current the page are not rendered), I focus to another tab (tab2). Now, network is normal, tab1 was rendered while I still focus on tab2. ***Example2***: tab1 is playing a video, I focus to another tab. At that time, the image will be different.

Comment: @MSalters, ***But I'm still not sure about it. Do you think it's right***

Comment: For IE you may have more luck wth the DWM thumb API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235681/how-do-i-display-open-ie-tabs-as-dwm-thumbnails although getting this to work for FF/Chrome is unlikely to work, as commented non visible windows are unlikely to be rendered and PrintWindow requires PrintWindow handling to have been built into the browser.

Comment: Since most (if not all) browsers implement windowless controls, they really only have a single client-area to render to. Tabs just give the **illusion** of multiple, discrete windows. @ZephyrPellerin: I don't see how Detours is of any help. It only allows you to observe the implementation. It does not provide facilities to trigger the rendering code to run.

Comment: @IInspectable Any hooked function can have functionality {pre,ap}ppended or replaced -- We no longer have to live in a world of `SetHookEx`. I don't think any other approach is sensible -- there is no way to "recieve" a GDI operation, it's effect is known through side-effects alone. You would *HAVE* to hook (or *directly* tamper with another process's address space).

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin: Since there is no designated function that marks the end of a paint cycle, you wouldn't know which function to detour. Unless I'm missing something significant, Detours is of little help here.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the original question but maybe a workaround:

You can use Microsoft UI Automation framework. It is a successor of Microsoft MSAA.

An example application is the inspect.exe application in the windows SDK.

If you open the inspect.exe application, then click on the address bar/tab etc, it will read out the text of this item.

UI Automation uses a client/provider architecture. So the application has to support it. All major browser or ui libraries do support this technique nowadays.

It also works for hidden/inactive/Maximized windows. It can traverse all open Chrome Windows/Chrome Tabs, regardless whether they are inactive or not.

Here you find official examples and official documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-walk-uiautomation-tree

A full example of those client/server applications can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/UIAutomationDocumentClient